# Calling Web Service periodically

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services

I have implemented a REST API in JAVA. I want to run this periodically, meaning, every week at a specified time. I am trying to automate this by calling web service via SQL server job. I am having trouble setting up this call. Every article I read either suggested it's a bad idea or its way too complicated to comprehend. Can anyone please help with an easy way to set up the call? Or if there are alternatives, which are those?

I have already tried:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                                                              'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                                                              'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

But I am not sure its safest option.

Comment: How about just using a Powershell job step, instead of a TSQL job step?

Comment: If every article is saying it's a bad idea...

Comment: Do you have authentication or other complex mechanisms in your service?  Is there any complex logic in the call?

Comment: Was looking for various options. Batch file for curl coupled with Task Scheduler worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options available to configure a scheduler to periodically invoke a web service call.

Option 1> The simplest one is to use the [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) utility within an linux system and schedule it in [crontab](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide) entry.

Example invocation: curl -XGET http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT

Option 2> The second option could is to schedule the wrapper shell script in an [Autosys](https://www.autosysguide.com/autosys-job-scheduler-tutorial/) configuration.

Option 3> If you are using a Java ecosystem, we can use the [Spring batch scheduling](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/job-scheduler-example/).

Comment: I wrote a batch file for curl to call web service and using Task Scheduler i automated it to run periodicall. Thank you for your response

Comment: if windows, can also use PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

I came across another alternative. You can run PowerShell Script in Sql Jobs. I wrote script to call Web Service and Sql Job to run script everyweek. Works perfectly.

Thank You.